# How do I change the color of a check mark to white in iOS Safari?

Tags: css, ios, safari

Currently, I have a heavy check mark ✔︎ (`&#10004;`) on my website. I need the color of the checkmark to be white so that it would appear correctly in dark mode.

```
<span style="color: white;">&#10004;</span>
```

It displays fine in Safari on Mac.

[image: Safari on Mac]

However, in Safari on iOS, it remains black.

[image: Safari on iOS]

How do I change the color of the checkmark to white in Safari on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An emoji is displayed in mobile Safari. Add `&#xFE0E;` after `&#10004;` should work.